# affect collection filters count in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

On my website, I show some products with a condition - if the product has a `test` tag:

```
{% if product.tags contains 'test' %}
   // render product
{% endif %}
```

And this way I get only some products, but the native product filter still displays the count of all products. I'll check it this way:

```
{% for filter in collection.filters %}
  {% for value in filter.values %}
    {{ value.count }}, 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And like I said, I get the full amount of products. But I want to get only the number of products that I displayed by condition. Can you please tell me how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the for-loop that you use to render products you can create a `count` variable and use it later.

pseudocode:

```
{% liquid
  assign counter = 0
  for product in products
     assign counter = counter | plus: 1
     render 'product-div'
  endfor
  render 'counter', count: counter
%}
```

this solution isn't elegant but the easiest one. If you need a counter in 'product-div' you can create two exact same for-loops: one for counting and second one for rendering.

Again, this solution is not the most clever one but the beauty lies in simplicity and simple code is always the best one

Comment: nice try but Liquid is not javascript

Comment: @OctavianFremen what's the point of this comment? Can you elaborate? The above code is a valid liquid code.

Comment: sorry but your code will throw a syntax error since you cannot use calculations in declarations. 
"assign counter = counter + 1" is not a valid liquid syntax

Comment: @OctavianFremen good point, it should be `| plus: 1` Yet pseudocode is not supposed to be runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is the following:

1. Loop through all products in your collection
2. Filter through them using your tag
3. Assign an index to each of those products
4. Then print the last recorded index
5. List item

In liquid this look pretty much like this:

```
{% for filter in collection.filters %}
 {% if product.tags contains 'test' %}
  {% if forloop.last %}
    {{forloop.index0}}
  {% endif%}
 {%endif %}
{% endfor%}
```